# Las preguntas deberían de mostrar esfuerzo e investigación por parte del autor

Tags: discusión, preguntas, pregunta-autorespondida

Estoy viendo preguntas y respuestas (usualmente auto-respondidas) del tipo:

> P: "Cual es la diferencia entre A y B?"
>
> R: "La diferencia es X"

De acuerdo al Centro de Ayuda, no deberían las preguntas mostrar al menos un poco de esfuerzo e investigación?.

Supongo que para algo están los libros.

Comment: El Centro de Ayuda dice : **si tu motivación es “Quisiera que otros me expliquen ______”, entonces está bien.** Parece que es un tipo de pregunta aceptable.

Answer (score 11):

Autorespondidas o no, toda pregunta debe evaluarse en aislamiento, como todo lo demás. El [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) dice:

> Si tienes una pregunta la cual ya conoces su respuesta, y quisieras mantener un registro público de ese conocimiento de tal manera que otros (incluyéndote a ti mismo) puedan encontrarlo luego, es perfectamente aceptable hacer una pregunta y responderla tú mismo en los sitios de Stack Exchange.

pero al mismo tiempo:

> También puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta, pero debes esperar 48 horas para poder hacerlo. **¡Después de todo, alguien más puede haber propuesto una mejor solución para tu problema!** (no me gusta la traducción de este texto :/ )

Tu pregunta no es solo para ti, también para los demás y tienes que respetar sus vistas que tengan al respecto.

Preferiblemente, no deberías de hacer autorespuestas de cosas triviales, que se pueden encontrar en cualquier parte, pero de problemas dificiles que no puedas encontrar. Somos expertos! Es imposible creer que no te hayas enfrentado a un problema el cual buscaste y no encontraste una solución. Ese es el tipo de preguntas autorespondidas que se fomentan.

Comment: Lo que es trivial para muchos de nosotros no lo es para otros. ¿Queremos hacer que el sitio sea hostil para los no expertos? En el punto 3 de un blog de SO podemos ver algunos de los usuarios potenciales. ¿No le estamos poniendo el listón demasiado alto a los nuevos usuarios de SOespañol que nunca han estado en el sitio inglés?

  El blog : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos nuevos o no, nuestra calidad no debe ser puesta en desventaja. Eso se ha discutido extensamente en SO y SE, y la conclusión es ["que algunas preguntas son demasiado simples para ser respondidas ... por lo menos en nuestros sitios"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). [**"La manera mas rápida de matar un Q&A es inundarlo de preguntas de baja calidad"**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), y no queremos esto. Convertir esSO en otro foro no puede ser nuestro proposito.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos tambien leé https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/

Comment: Pues sí. Otra cara de esta moneda. Ni pasarse ni quedarse corto de estricto es bueno. Intentemos que, siguiendo el espíritu del blog que enlazas, nuestra interacción con quienes no se ajustan a nuestro estandard sea una invitación a mejorar y no un rechazo.

Answer (score 3):

> > P: "Cual es la diferencia entre A y B?"
> >     R: "La diferencia es X"
>
> De acuerdo al Centro de Ayuda, no deberían las preguntas mostrar al menos un poco de esfuerzo e investigación?.

Depende de la pregunta en sí, y de qué sean `A`, `B` y `X`.

Por ejemplo, hay temas que no se pueden detallar más porque se explican solos, y se saben o no se saben, pero no hay forma de mostrar más esfuerzo en la pregunta. Un caso puntual para mí sería: "[¿Como veo el número mágico 0xCAFEBABE?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/272/127)". Acá no hay mucho más que decir (se conoce o no).

En cambio, para cualquier pregunta a la que, en tu opinión profesional, les falte esfuerzo de investigación, que sufran el castigo y tengan que esconderse de vergüenza!!!

[image: Off topic]

<sup>* Al menos hasta que se traduzca esa parte :)</sup>

Esto para mí es totalmente independiente de si son auto-respondidas o no. Evaluemos las preguntas auto-respondidas con el mismo criterio que cualquier otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Las preguntas que se publican para ser auto respondidas, como menciona [Braiam](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152/braiam) en su [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/106/65), deben seguir los lineamientos de StackOverflow en Español, de hecho, deberían ser ejemplo de lo que una buena pregunta debe incluir.

Quien redacta la pregunta, debe asumir el papel de quien tiene una pregunta, podría mencionar las fuentes básicas de consulta asumiendo los errores típicos de investigación, por ejemplo la lectura apresurada o bien carente de la compresión de conceptos clave que en la respuesta serán develados

Por otro lado, cuando el caso así lo amerite, la respuesta puede hacer referencia a fuentes avanzadas o difíciles de encontrar.

Obviamente, en los casos en que las respuestas están basadas en "conocimiento de dominio público" o bien en la experiencia o discernimiento del autor no requieren referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora mismo, somos muchos que ya conocemos *cómo funciona el sistema* <sup>**[1]**</sup> y que frecuentamos desde hace tiempo el Stack Overflow que se convirtió en una referencia global en programación y que ha gestado la red de sites de preguntas y respuestas Stack Exchange.

Sí no me engaña la memoria, cuando estaban construyendo el SO original, *mostrar esfuerzo de investigación* no era un problema, pues la intención era crear una base de datos de Preguntas y Respuestas que respondieran a *todos* (el máximo posible) de problemas que programadores enfrentan en su día a día.

**Cuando alguien pregunte a Google**, en Español, "Cómo resolver tal cosa?", **queremos que venga a nuestro site, ¿si o no?**

Este punto y coma en el *tooltip* de voto positivo, ¿significa `o` o significa `y` o significa `y/o`?


<kbd>[image]</kbd>

¿Puedo votar +1 sí es útil y clara solamente?

<sup>**[1]** Conocer las reglas del juego da ventajas iniciales, yes. Uno puede aprovecharse de eso para beneficio personal pura y simplemente (mensaje a la comunidad: ustedes no me importan mucho) o puede ayudar a preparar la casa para cuando lleguen las hordas de programadores inquisidores. Por supuesto, hay mucho camino entre un opuesto y otro.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Este tipo de preguntas no necesariamente merecen ser cerradas. Recuerda que los usuarios harán este tipo de preguntas si no pueden leer la documentación en inglés.

Mientras la pregunta sea útil y pueda ser respondida de forma objetiva no creo que deba cerrada.

Comment: No he sugerido que sean cerradas... solo quería invitar a la discusión sobre este tema.