# ¿Cómo podemos contribuir todos para que las preguntas sean más precisas, menos ambiguas, etc?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Quiero participar en Stack Overflow en español resolviendo dudas principalmente de Ruby on Rails, pero al leer varias preguntas no logro entender qué es lo que los programadores requieren. Pongo a consideración compartir consejos para escribir mejores preguntas, mejores descripciones de los problemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español :)

El problema que planteas es uno de los más importantes de esta comunidad (y de otras de StackExchange), pero tambien uno muy complejo de resolver. De todas maneras, todos los consejos para realizar una buena pregunta están ya compilados en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), por lo que la práctica habitual cuando nos encontramos con una pregunta que no está clara, es añadir un comentario a dicha página,así como al [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Así mismo, es útil también pedir las aclaraciones necesarias en los comentarios y sugerir al autor cómo editar la pregunta para que pueda recibir ayuda.

Comment: Habría que considerar que para comentar en cualquier publicación se requieren 50 pts de reputación.

Comment: Por supuesto @Rubén...por eso es labor de la gente con al menos 50 de reputación informar sobre la forma de preguntar. Si tienes menos,lamentablemente tendrás que esperar a que otros aclaren la pregunta

Comment: La mención es porque el OP tiene <50 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de contribuir a documentar soluciones a problemas es publicar preguntas o problemas que has tenido en el pasado o que piensas que podrían tener alguien más y de forma simultánea publicar la respuesta.

Es un poco complicado porque aunque ya se conozca la respuesta / solución la pregunta de todas formas debería seguir los lineamientos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Relacionado:

- [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/65)
- [Las preguntas deberían de mostrar esfuerzo e investigación por parte del autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/65)

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas que se rescato así rápidamente de [esta guía](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) son:

- Intentar preguntar con la mayor información técnica posible y de forma especifica.
- Aborde el problema especifico, si tiene varios problemas escriba varias preguntas en diferentes posts.
- Use buena puntuación, recuerde que una mala puntuación puede cambiar el sentido de la pregunta.
- Las preguntas son en su mayoría técnicas por lo tanto por favor intente ser lo mas técnico posible, esto incluso ayuda mucho a su aprendizaje del lenguaje/framework/etc.
- Lee antes de publicar, algo que puede ayudar es realizar la pregunta a alguien (o hacer como si alguien mas lo estuviera leyendo) mas antes de hacer el publicar la pregunta.

Como comunidad es muy importante realimentar nuestros esfuerzos, sobre todo los esfuerzos para aprender. Con una "mayor claridad" vamos a mejorar personalmente, vamos a poder ayudar a otros, va a ser mas fácil encontrar un problema y buscarlo cuando lo tengamos. Lo mejor es que va a ser en nuestro propio idioma. Gracias.