# ¿Por qué estas preguntas basicamente iguales fueron recibidas de diferente forma?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Por un lado tenemos [Para que sirve “=>” en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3767/2027) (Febrero de 2016) y por el otro [Para que sirve Convert.ToSingle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/98832/2027) (Agosto de 2017)

La anatomía de ambas preguntas es:

---

### Para que sirve `{var}`

Vi este código

`{codigo con var}`

---

El problema es que una de las preguntas, la más antigua, recibió buena atención con votos positivos y buenas respuestas de parte de @CarlosMuñoz y @Jorgesys

Y tristemente la otra no, mandaban al usuario a la documentación. Ademas de que todos los que respondieron tienen una puntuación de 0 en este momento.

Además, tiene un voto de cierre por parte de @CarlosMuñoz el mismo usuario que respondio la pregunta anterior.

¿Acaso ha cambiado tanto el sitio en un año?

Deberíamos tener el mismo criterio para evaluar las preguntas. No veo el problema de tener estas preguntas "básicas" en el sitio. Y mas por tener el precedente de tener una pregunta idéntica.

Comment: Muy buena reflexión. A mi parecer, ambas preguntas tienen el mismo grado de esfuerzo e investigación (nulo) y las trataría igual. Ya opiné en [el cuestionario a moderador](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2478/2017-elecci%C3%B3n-de-moderador-cuestionario/2499#2499)(pregunta #6) que las respuestas que se basan en una simple busqueda, si la respuesta no es una copia de la documentacion y tiene *miga* y una explicacion detallada y elaborada, entonces bienvenida.

Comment: En mi caso particular, he visto ya 3 preguntas del OP sobre casi lo mismo la clase `Convert`. La primera pregunta la respondí, la siguientela contesté pero también lo mande a cerrar como duplicado. Esta última no es exactamente un duplicado pero trata casi sobre lo mismo. Una cosa es desconocimiento, otra parece ser la falta intención de aprender y querer que le den la respuesta ya servida.

Comment: Considero que en Meta se deberían señalar las acciones a discutir sin nombrar directamente a los actores. Cuando se trate de una situación particular de un individuo primero debería hablarse en privado directamente con esa persona o hacer un reporte para que un moderador diamantado se haga cargo.

Comment: @Rubén gracias, lo tomare en cuenta, es que esta vez hasta fui por el al chat :P

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en pasar, espero no haberte incomodado mucho

Comment: Para nada, al contrario la observación es válida. Yo mismo dudé en si responder o no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La primer pregunta tiene más de un año, es de cuando el sitio tenía apenas unas pocas semanas en beta pública, la segunda pregunta apenas tiene hora y es de año y medio después. No me parece extraño que tengan tratamientos distintos, sin embargo, me parece apropiado identificar este tipo de situaciones.

Considero que el curso de acción es clarificar el tipo de publicaciones que queremos y votar en consecuencia. Por otro lado, el que una "mala" pregunta tenga una buena respuesta o no, no debería condicionar la votación de la pregunta.

Relacionado:

- [Las preguntas deberían de mostrar esfuerzo e investigación por parte del autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/65)

Comment: Respecto a tu ultima frase, exacto, hay [preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg/1943#comment5841_1943) que se salvaron gracias a la calidad de sus respuestas, pero para votar hay dos sitios distintos

Comment: El problema de tratar las preguntas con independencia de las respuestas es que entonces es imposible tratar las respuestas con independencia de las preguntas.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Considerando el hecho de que se debería valorar si la respuesta responde a la pregunta, así es, es imposible tratar las respuestas con independencia absoluta de las preguntas :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo @Rubén. Si nos fijamos en Stack Overflow en inglés,hay preguntas muy básicas con una buena acogida que datan de los origenes del sitio, que hoy en dia no serían bien recibidas y que probablemente acabarían cerradas. Es normal tener un poco de "manga ancha" al principio, pero por ejemplo en el caso que nos ocupa,una simple búsqueda en Google habría resuelto la duda en menos tiempo del que tomó realizar la pregunta, con lo que es comprensible la acogida que ha tenido.

Comment: ¿Votar a cierre como duplicado, quizás?